# C# dynamically generated controls in Page_Load or PreRender?

Tags: c#, pageload, prerender

I have a c# web application where I need to dynamically generate controls, and where the actions on the controls also affect which controls will be rendered. Imagine for example a list of buttons, where each button should remove itself (and its reference in the database). I have the feeling I don't understand something quite basic here (at least it should be)

I would like to use event handlers here. However, the question is then where should I generate the controls, in Page_Load or PreRender? If I generate them in page_load the event handlers haven't fired yet so the generated content isnt up to date yet. I can also generate it in PreRender but then the event handlers don't fire because the controls dont exist yet.

What would be the preferred way of handling this? I really want to avoid the option to modify the generated content later, it is way too error-prone in my case. I would like to generate all content from scratch, right after the events have been handled. Currently I solve this partially by examining the request.form before the generation of the controls but I have quite a lot of actions and it's not really a workable solution in quite some cases already.

Comment: ASP.NET lifecycle on MSDN recommends PreInit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I create controls by overriding OnInit

That means they are available for the viewstate to restore any values to them, OnLoad is too late for this.

PreRender is for last minute things like populating textboxes and rendering scripts

Note however your controls must rebuild after a postback in exactly the same way for the values to be restored (same IDs etc).

Comment: How does that help me. That would create the same problem as when I generate them in OnLoad - events havent been handled yet.

Comment: Ah I see the problem, you want to create controls in response to the events which were fired.  As you say you have to do it after the event so OnPreRender is an option as is the event method itself, however you may have viewstate issues for the reason I mentioned before.  I would turn off viewstate for those controls.  Could you build these controls in javascript?  That would save you a postback, there are numerous methods of capturing values (populate a asp.net HiddenTextbox for example?

Comment: Let me rephrase the question. How can you handle events in the case that you cannot be sure the control will be there next time the page renders? That doesnt seem like a weird question and it appears weird to me that this is seemingly so hard to do in .Net